# How can I setup my hugo url so I can list all desired urls under a certain URL path?

Tags: url, hugo, static-site

I have a urls like this:

https://mfaani.com/posts/foo/bar
https://mfaani.com/posts/foo/baz
https://mfaani.com/posts/foo/qud

I want users to be able to see all my "foo" blog posts at the following URL:

https://mfaani.com/posts/foo or perhaps https://mfaani.com/foo

But that returns a 404.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually very simple.

Under the `https://mfaani.com/posts/foo/` just add an empty `_index.md` file.

That will then add all your posts for that category.

### Note:

It's good idea to add frontmatter to the `_index.md` page. Because if you've nested one directory in another, then it will use the `_index.md` of the subdirectory to know how to include the description of the subdirectory the list page.

For example if the `_index.md` is *empty* then you'll see:

[image]

---

Alternatively if you add the following frontmatter, then you'll see something like the following:

```
---
Title: '⚡️ SERIES -  Optimizing App Size'
---

A description of the post goes here.
```

[image]